# How can I tell maven to use specific settings.xml on project bases?

Tags: maven

So my project comes with `settings.xml` together with its `pom.xml`.

Is there any way in `pom.xml` to specify to use the `settings.xml` in the same folder?

Comment: A project which comes with special settings.xml sounds strange...can you elaborate a little bit more what you like to achieve?

Comment: @khmarbaise settings.xml comes with an additional repository - username and password and I want to publish it together with source code.

Comment: Bad practice. Better use a repository manager and describe the things you need.

Comment: http://maven.apache.org/repository-management.html

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It seems that Maven does not allow what you are trying to do, and moreover specifically advised against it. The following excerpt is taken from the official documentation which is [Apache Maven - Settings Reference](https://maven.apache.org/settings.html):

> The settings element in the settings.xml file contains elements used
> to define values which configure Maven execution in various ways, like
> the pom.xml, but should not be bundled to any specific project, or
> distributed to an audience. These include values such as the local
> repository location, alternate remote repository servers, and
> authentication information.
>
> There are two locations where a settings.xml file may live:
>
> ```
> The Maven install: $M2_HOME/conf/settings.xml
> A user's install: ${user.home}/.m2/settings.xml
> ```
>
> The former settings.xml are also called global settings, the latter
> settings.xml are referred to as user settings. If both files exists,
> their contents gets merged, with the user-specific settings.xml being
> dominant.

Comment: only issue is when you are in different projects, different customers, you can not simply or easily merge them and they both supply a settings.xml of their own. you need to keep replacing it as you switch project you are working on. pain in the ass. rather  the pom.xml could define the settings.xml name at least to look for.

Answer (score 4):

If someone is still interested, at least with Maven 3.6.3 you can specify the path to the user settings file as an argument with

```
-s /path/to/user/settings.xml
```

Likewise, the path to the global settings is specified with

```
-gs /path/to/global/settings.xml
```

Comment: That only works when you are in charge of maven, in intellij this is not possible per project.